# Incorrect Resource URL - New Install

Tags: wordpress, resource-urls

I am getting a red "Incorrect Resource URL" notice, but I can't see that anything's set incorrectly. I read elsewhere that this should result in the little arrows missing from drop-down menus, but I'm not having that problem.

WordPress install. (New - been working on it over the last week or so. Haven't gone live yet.)

I also read that this may be due to issues with symlinking, so I've used an absolute URL, not a relative one. I can access the exact location via, e.g. FTP, using the path I've put into the "CiviCRM Resource URL" field on the "Settings - Resource URLs" page.

The path I have is: /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm

Help?

Comment: I wrote this check; if you want to ping me at chat.civicrm.org (username: @junglebird) I can take a look at it with you.

Answer (score 2):

We are seeing this same issue and reported it here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21785?jql=text%20~%20%22resource%20url%22. It appears to be a false positive however.